# How can I fetch current pair prices through uniswap-v2 API?

Tags: uniswap, price, exchange-api

I need to quote online prices of different token pairs through uniswap-v2 API. As the below picture shows, I tend to pass token pair (maybe with base token desired amount) to the API and get all price related values as result.

[image]

I found `Fetcher.fetchPairData` method in [uniswap documentions](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/SDK/fetcher/), but it does not return the correct values. Am I using the correct method or I have to use another method for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Sticking to Uniswap SDK terms, a "pair price" strictly speaking does not exist. The closest thing to it is the *MidPrice* of a given *Route*.

However, your screenshot indicates that what you're really looking for is the **ExecutionPrice** of a *Trade*:

```
import { ChainId, Token, WETH, Fetcher, Trade, Route, TokenAmount, TradeType } from '@uniswap/sdk'

const DAI = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F', 18)
const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(DAI, WETH[DAI.chainId])    
const route = new Route([pair], WETH[DAI.chainId])    
const trade = new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(WETH[DAI.chainId], '1000000000000000000'), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT)

console.log(trade.executionPrice.toSignificant(6))
```

Comment: @pwagnet Thanks for your answer but I already have tested `executionPrice` and its value is not even close to what I see through UniSwap UI.

Comment: @pwagner I've asked similar quesiton in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944736/fetch-proper-execution-price-from-uniswap-v2. 

Why some prices fetched, with similar code to yours are so accurate and some are not even close?

Comment: I guess the issue is that "Disable Multihops" is not turned on in the Uniswap UI settings.

Comment: What to do when the pair of the tokens does not exists ? For example If i want to retrive the Route object for the following tokens

TOKEN-A: `0x3301ee63fb29f863f2333bd4466acb46cd8323e6`
TOKEB-B: `0xf32aa187d5bc16a2c02a6afb7df1459d0d107574`

Answer (score 4):

This has been a pain for me for a long time. You basically have to compare the liquidity of the different pairs and run the Uniswap formula for calculating the price.

`Y * I / (X + I)`

- I is your input amount of source tokens
- X is the balance of the pool
  in the source token
- Y is the balance of the pool in the target token

In the end, the process we came up to get the price of all Uniswap pairs was the following.

1. Find all token pairs by looking at all historical PairCreated
   events.
2. Read the reserves from token0 and token1 from the pair
3. Calculate the price of token0 and token1 in usd according to the uniswap formula.

This took us a lot of work to do, especially when you need it for multiple tokens and on multiple chains (maybe you want the same on pancake).

Anyway, we took our solution and we turned it into an API you can use if you want. It's the [Moralis](https://moralis.io/) Deep Index API. You simply run

```
/token/ERC20/{TOKEN_ADDRESS}/price
```

This will give you the exact same price you see on, for example, Etherscan. It currently supports ethereum, bsc and polygon. And it's free.

Disclaimer, I work at moralis and we developed this API.

Comment: Is there a way to filter API responses? For example, instruct the API so that it only returns a single value of the token price and nothing else.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not format the response structure yourself